# Macro to rearrange compound initializer in C

Tags: c, gcc, macros

INTRODUCTION

I belive mistakes can be avoided by assigning register values of a microcontroller in the same order they were described in the manufacturer's datasheet. I came out with the following solution:

```
struct myBits
{
   uint32_t b00 : 1;
   uint32_t b01 : 1;
   uint32_t b02 : 1;
    ...
   uint32_t b30 : 1;
   uint32_t b31 : 1;
};


// PIOB->        offset: PIO_CODR
// 0x400E1000U           0x00000034U
(*(volatile uint32_t*)0x400E1034U) = *(uint32_t*)&(struct myBits) {
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*|    B31    |    B30    |    B29    |    B28    |    B27    |    B26    |    B25    |    B24    |*/
.b31=   0   ,.b30=  0   ,.b29=  0   ,.b28=  0   ,.b27=  0   ,.b26=  0   ,.b25=  0   ,.b24=  0     ,
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*|    B23    |    B22    |    B21    |    B20    |    B19    |    B18    |    B17    |    B16    |*/
.b23=   0   ,.b22=  0   ,.b21=  0   ,.b20=  0   ,.b19=  0   ,.b18=  0   ,.b17=  0   ,.b16=  0     ,
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*|    B15    |    B14    |    B13    |    B12    |    B11    |    B10    |    B09    |    B08    |*/
.b15=   0   ,.b14=  0   ,.b13=  0   ,.b12=  0   ,.b11=  0   ,.b10=  0   ,.b09=  0   ,.b08=  0     ,
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*|    B07    |    B06    |    B05    |    B04    |    B03    |    B02    |    B01    |    P00    |*/
.b07=   0   ,.b06=  0   ,.b05=  0   ,.b04=  0   ,.b03=  0   ,.b02=  0   ,.b01=  0   ,.b00=  0      };
```

PROBLEM

I would love having a macro to flip the struct values in the compound assignment to eliminate the need for designations:

```
// PIOB->        offset: PIO_CODR
// 0x400E1000U           0x00000034U
(*(volatile uint32_t*)0x400E1034U) = *(uint32_t*)&(struct myBits) desiredMacro ({
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*|    B31    |    B30    |    B29    |    B28    |    B27    |    B26    |    B25    |    B24    |*/
        0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     1     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0    ,
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*|    B23    |    B22    |    B21    |    B20    |    B19    |    B18    |    B17    |    B16    |*/
        0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*|    B15    |    B14    |    B13    |    B12    |    B11    |    B10    |    B09    |    B08    |*/
        0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*|    B07    |    B06    |    B05    |    B04    |    B03    |    B02    |    B01    |    P00    |*/
        0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0      });
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance. Hope my ASCII art inspires the community.

Comment: When doing the assignment without a macro I get the BIT 31 to be the least significant binary digit. I will recheck I didn't state a non-working solution by ordering the struct the other way round, sorry if that's the case. I'm looking to have the first member of the struct be the most significant digit of the uint32_t assignment.

Comment: Ohh, I see, sorry about that, didn't see the order correctly.

Comment: No problem. I've been reversing the struct order all day long so it could've been my fault. Compiled the code to confirm and seems the question arrangement was fine.

Comment: If you're willing to vary the syntax slightly, you can do `#define REVERSE(b0, b1, ..., b31) b31, b30, ..., b0` and then `*ptr = *(uint32_t)&(struct myBits) { REVERSE( 0,0,1,...) };`.  Note that your type pun is a separate problem because it violates strict aliasing.  Better to do `*(volatile struct myBits *)0xdeadbeef = (struct myBits) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION

Revisited one of my previous macro attempts due to Nate Eldredge's proposed solution. This time I wrote the macro correctly and worked.

```
#define invertMacro(b31,b30,b29,b28,b27,b26,b25,b24,b23,b22,b21,b20,b19,b18,b17,b16,b15,b14,b13,b12,b11,b10,b09,b08,b07,b06,b05,b04,b03,b02,b01,b00) b00,b01,b02,b03,b04,b05,b06,b07,b08,b09,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16,b17,b18,b19,b20,b21,b22,b23,b24,b25,b26,b27,b28,b29,b30,b31

// PIOB->        offset: PIO_CODR
// 0x400E1000U           0x00000034U
(*(volatile uint32_t*)0x400E1034U) = *(uint32_t*)&(struct myBits) { invertMacro (
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*|    B31    |    B30    |    B29    |    B28    |    B27    |    B26    |    B25    |    B24    |*/
        0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0    ,
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*|    B23    |    B22    |    B21    |    B20    |    B19    |    B18    |    B17    |    B16    |*/
        0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*|    B15    |    B14    |    B13    |    B12    |    B11    |    B10    |    B09    |    B08    |*/
        0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*|    B07    |    B06    |    B05    |    B04    |    B03    |    B02    |    B01    |    P00    |*/
        0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0     ,     0      )};
```

When copying this code, note his suggestion to avoid violating strict aliasing while punning.